# jquery select a column's last cell

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for a way to select the Last Cell from a table column.
This column has a class of ".B89", which is what I'm attempting to select from.

Here's what I've attempted, and got so far, but it's not working.

```
$('table#incometable th.B89:last-child').html("data to show!!!");
```

---

The table is dynamically created, so I'll do a simplified version:

```
<table id="incometable"> 
    <tr>
        <th class="B89">Dude 1</th> 
        <th class="B55">Dude 2</th> 
        <th class="B78">Dude 3</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>float values</td> 
        <td>float values</td> 
        <td>float values</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>float values</td> 
        <td>float values</td> 
        <td>float values</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>float values</td> 
        <td>float values</td> 
        <td>float values</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>---This Cell needs to be modified---</td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't tell without seeing your markup, but I have a feeling that you may be trying to reference the last column by its header `<th class='B89'>`.

If so, you can get the `.index()` from that cell, then select the last row and get the `<td>` at that index.

```
  //---v----------make sure the DOM is loaded
$(function() {
    var table = $('#incometable');
    var idx = table.find('th.B89').index();

    table.find('tr:last > td').eq( idx ).html("data to show!!!");
});
```

- Cache the `$('#incometable')` selection.
- [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the `th.B89`
- Get the [`index()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the `th.B89`
- Get the `:last` row's `<td>` elements, and select one with the same index using the [`eq()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

Comment: I tested it, and it's still not detecting that last column cell.

Comment: @user: It works for me. [See an example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2CBm/2/) Also, make sure the DOM is loaded before the code runs. I'll update my answer with a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need the :last selector insead of :last-child, since you want the last cell in the collumn, not row.

also THs should be in the first row so you probably search for a td.

it's still difficult to tell without knowing your table html.

```
$('table#incometable td.B89:last')
```